# shift+insert not working in emacs 25

Tags: emacs, emacs25

In emacs 23 there was an option where we can select the word with mouse and using cntrl+s we can paste that word to search. 
Unfortunately this is not working in emacs 25. I didnt change the configuration file . I took the emacs code from the git hub and compiled. I am using Centos6.4 version

I have already tried this

> (setq select-enable-clipboard t)
>   and
>   (x-get-selection-value)

But none of it helped me

Comment: The question is not clear. Please provide a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file) to reproduce what you see. And describe what you expected to see instead. Specify your platform etc. IOW, provide the info you would be expected to provide in a bug report.

Comment: This question appears to be about **general computing hardware and software**, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It is probably better suited to the [emacs.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply (!) select the word with the mouse and type M-w C-s RET C-y RET C-s C-s

Here are the details:

- select the word with the mouse
- M-w (to copy to clipboard)
- C-s RET (to start incremental search and switch to non-incremental search)
- (or 'FIND' if you have this key on your keyboard)
- C-y (to paste from clipboard)
- RET (to start searching)
- C-s C-s (to search other occurrences)

Answer (score 0):

Add `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)` to your .emacs

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.